# how to combine python into wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

Hello I am an amateur programmer. I built a simple text twister game and named it as texttwister_compy.py. I also have been able to build a simple GUI. But I need to learn how to integrate my python program into my wxpython GUI.
Here is my wxpython code:

```
import os
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(200,100))
        self.Control=wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.CreateStatusBar()

        filemenu=wx.Menu()
        editmenu=wx.Menu()
        viewmenu=wx.Menu()
        toolsmenu=wx.Menu()

        menuAbout=filemenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, "&About")
        menuExit=filemenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, "&Exit")
        menuOpen=filemenu.Append(wx.ID_OPEN, "&Open")
        menuCopy=editmenu.Append(wx.ID_COPY, "&COPY")
        menuClear=viewmenu.Append(wx.ID_CLEAR, "&Clear")
        clearButton=wx.Button(self, wx.ID_CLEAR, "Clear")

        menuBar=wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(filemenu, "&file")
        menuBar.Append(editmenu, "&Edit")
        menuBar.Append(viewmenu, "&View")
        menuBar.Append(toolsmenu, "&Tools")
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnAbout, menuAbout)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, menuExit)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnOpen, menuOpen)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnCopy, menuCopy)
        self.Show(True)

    def OnAbout(self, event):
        devi=wx.MessageDialog(self, "small text editpr", wx.OK)
        devi.ShowModal()
        devi.Destroy()

    def OnExit(self, event):
        self.Close(True)

    def OnOpen(self, event):
        self.dirname=''
        dlg=wx.FileDialog(self, "choose file", self.dirname, "*.*", wx.OPEN)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.filename = dlg.GetFilename()
            self.dirname = dlg.GetDirectory()
            f = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'r')
            self.control.SetValue(f.read())
            f.close()
        dlg.Destroy()

    def OnCopy(self, event):
        mk=wx.EditDialog(self, "Copy files", wx.OK)
        mk=ShowModal()

    def OnClear(self, event):
        clearButton.ShowModal()

app=wx.App(False)
frame=MainWindow(None, "Hello commander")
app.MainLoop()
```

I also have a question regarding the demos in wxpython question, how exactly are you to open them.

My final question is how do you do that?

So here is the program for the texttwister:

```
import random
list=[['D','R','P','O','O','L','E','Q','U','A'],['L','A','C','I','T','Y','L','A','N','A'],
      ['I','S','T','M','E','C','H','Y','R',],['O','C','R','I','G','N','A'],
      ['M','E','I','D','C','I','E','N'],['N','O','S','S','I','M','I','E'],
      ['Y','M','E','C','H','L','A'],['D','A','G','R','U'],['I','E','V','D']]
list2=['quadropole', 'analytical', 'alchemy','chemistry', 'organic',
       'medicine', 'emission','durga','devi']
random.choice(list)

def operation():
    print random.choice(list)

x=operation()

while True:
    from itertools import repeat

    guess=raw_input('please untwist the word:')

    if guess in list2:
        print 'CONGRATULATIONS! you got the word'
        print 'keep going strong'
        repeat(operation())
        continue
    if guess not in list2:
        print 'NO! this is not correct wrong answer please try again'  

    if guess==raw_input():
        print 'Program is CLOSING'
        print 'Please have a good day'
        print 'hope you enjoyed the game'
        break
```

How do I integrate this with the code above? So my main loop would be like a class or a function like say class `Loop`. Then in the main wxpython do I call it as a class or a function?

Answer (score 2):

Simply bind your action events to your button or mouse clicks. So if your game involves changing the number in a box and incrementing it one for every click a simple call to your function in the game to as input and update the GUI. On that click its not only supposed to update the box, but do something in your game that can have consequences or rewards, which will then reflect back onto your GUI (ie. updating your score).

Though by this point your game will likely need to be in OOP form, as procedural will not likely work well for this.

Testing the test cases, you first need to find the examples. Often they are located in your python-directory/wxpython/examples for most modules. You'll find them, and launch them like you would any other python script. Often there will be a readme, and the wxpython docs also tell you what to do.